# Controller action method not being called making a post request in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use model binding to send a file selected by the user to the controller, this action method is not being hit and I am not sure why. I put a breakpoint inside but it will not get hit.

Here is my import view:

```
@model FileModel

<h1 class="title-underline">Import file</h1>

<div class="form-group">
    <form asp-controller="Import" asp-action="FileImport" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="importFile">Select a past grant to import</label>
        <input type="file" id="importFile" name="importFile" asp-for="ImportFile">
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-tnl btn-block">Import</button>
</div>
```

Here is my model:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public IFormFile ImportFile { set; get; }
}
```

Here is my action method inside my ImportController:

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult FileImport(FileModel model)
    {
        IFormFile file = model.ImportFile;

        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var contentType = file.ContentType;



        return View("Index");

    }
```

I have provided the controller, action, method, and enctype so I'm not sure what else is missing which is stopping the method from being hit. Is it something to do with the model in the parameter?

Comment: You missing `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. Might that be the problem?

Comment: @Ergis No I don't think that is the problem, when I remove the ValidateAntiForgeryToken, it still will not work.

Comment: Wow, you literally set the submit button outside the form. I didn't expect that so i didn't even see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I see is the submit button is outside of the form. It is not doing anything when you click it. Try bringing it into the `<form>...</form>` block and make the input type = "submit", not "button". Or write a click handler for it that would call submit on the form.

You can check the syntax here
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form asp-controller="Import" asp-action="FileImport" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="importFile">Select a past grant to import</label>
        <input type="file" id="importFile" name="importFile" asp-for="ImportFile">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-tnl btn-block" value="Import">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should be inside form tag. Not outside.

```
<form>
   <button type="submit">Import</button>
</form>
```